# How to use Firebase Google.Apis.CloudFunctions in .NET c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have created several Firebase Google Cloud Functions that are working fine with my Flutter app. However I also need to access these functions via a .NET c# WPF Desktop program.

I understand there is a nuget package called Google.Apis.CloudFunctions, which I have imported, but the documentation is very limited and I can't figure out how to call the Google Cloud Functions.

In DART/flutter I simply use:

```
final HttpsCallable identifyMember = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(
            functionName: 'identifyMember',
          );

final HttpsCallableResult result = await identifyMember.call(
              <String, dynamic>{
                'firstName': _firstNameTextController.text,
                'lastName': _lastNameTextController.text,
          });
```

Does anyone know how to perform something similar in .NET c# wpf?

Thanks!
Damian

Comment: Why the downvoting? This is not a reasonable request? Seems rather limited if Firebase Cloud Functions can't be accessed from a .NET application? No?

Comment: Seems like a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to invoke a [Firebase callable function](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js), you will either need one of the provided client libraries, or you will have to [implement the protocol yourself](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference).  A client library isn't provided for .NET, so you should probably look into implementing that spec.

Comment: Thanks, but what is the point of the Google.Apis.CloudFunctions nuget package then? I use the Google.Cloud.Firestore nuget package to connect to FireStore via the wpf app, wouldn't the same principle apply for CloudFunctions?

Comment: If you mean [this package](https://googleapis.dev/dotnet/Google.Apis.CloudFunctions.v1/latest/api/Google.Apis.CloudFunctions.v1.html), that has nothing to do with Firebase callable functions.